# Some Wordpress staging multilingual sites point to production

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, multisite

I'm a developer and one of our new businesses has a Wordpress multilingual mulitsite. They have a Staging and Production environment. While in their Staging admin panel I noticed two of the five sites are pointing to Production. So if I attempt to go to those sites to make changes I am redirected from the Worpdress Staging admin to Wordpress Production admin. Currently the sites are hosted on WPEngine.

Here is how the links to the sites currently look:

```
China: website.staging.wpengine.com/china/wp-admin/
Japan: website.staging.wpengine.com/japan/wp-admin/

APAC: www.website.com/apac/wp-admin/
EMEA: www.website.com/emea/wp-admin/

Main: website.staging.wpengine.com/wp-admin/
```

Anyone with an idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a Production url in the staging database tables in phpMyAdmin that I missed changing to staging url when I did my last deploy from Production to Staging.